# Can I use the <nav> tag for pagination?

Tags: html, pagination, semantic-markup

It's very common to see the usage of the tag `<nav>` in a main menu navigation, but I don't know other examples where I can use it. For example, for pagination:

```
<div class='my-pagination'>
   <!-- first, 2, 3, 4 ... 8, 9, last -->
</div>
```

Can be:

```
<nav class='my-pagination'>
  <!-- first, 2, 3, 4 ... 8, 9, last -->
</nav>
```

Is it semantic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes.**

The HTML5 spec defines the [`nav` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-nav-element) like this:

> The `nav` element represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.

Pagination clearly consists of "links to other pages", and these are "navigation links". And in probably most cases it makes sense to use a sectioning content element for this.

---

Make sure to place the `nav` in the correct parent section:

- If it’s a multi-paged article, the `nav` should be a child of the `article`.

  ```
  <article>
    <h1>Review of my new camera</h1>
    <p>…</p>
    <nav><!-- pagination for this article --></nav>
  </article>
  ```
- If it’s a multi-paged list of article teasers, the `nav` should be a child of the section containing this list.

  ```
  <section>
    <h1>All blog posts</h1>
    <article><h1>Review of my new camera</h1></article>
    <article><h1>I want to buy a camera, any suggestions?</h1></article>
    <nav><!-- pagination for this blog posts list --></nav>
  </section>
  ```
- If it’s one full article per page, the `nav` should be a child of the `body` sectioning root.

  ```
  <body>
    <article><h1>Review of my new camera</h1></article>
    <nav><!-- pagination for next/previous article --></nav>
  </body>
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question.

As per the official [W3 Draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element) it seems that the `nav` would indeed be appropriate for use as a pagination container, particularly if it's intended for primary navigation (that is the whole page is a result set that can be paged through)

> Not all groups of links on a page need to be in a nav element — the element is primarily intended for sections that consist of major navigation blocks. In particular, it is common for footers to have a short list of links to various pages of a site, such as the terms of service, the home page, and a copyright page. The footer element alone is sufficient for such cases; while a nav element can be used in such cases, it is usually unnecessary.

Comment: Well... 'yes' if your pagination is paging through a result set that is the primary data on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you use your pagination.  If you're doing it for search results and clicking the page link takes the user to a new url, then yes.  If clicking the page button triggers a refresh of the search result content, then no.

the Nav element is designed to help users find links to other pages not to a set of button controls for a widget.